# .preventDefault not working properly inside lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a `lightbox` for a simple gallery of 6 images (an ordered list).

```
    <ol id=image_gallery>

      <li><a href="images/depression.jpg"><img src="images/depression.jpg"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/solitude.jpg"><img src="images/solitude.jpg" ></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/photo1.png"><img src="images/photo1.png" ></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/photo2.png"><img src="images/photo2.png" ></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/green.png"><img src="images/green.png" ></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/yellow.png"><img src="images/yellow.png" ></a></li>

    </ol>
```

It seems that I have an issues and I can't figure it out which one is it

```
      var $overlay = $('<div id= "overlay"></div>');// the overlay which will be added
      var $image = $("<img>"); // the image which will be added to the overlay

      $overlay.append($image);// we append the image to the overlay
      $("body").append($overlay);// we append the overlay to the body

      $("#image_gallery a").click(function(event){
           event.preventDefault();
      var imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");
      $image.attr("src", imageLocation); 

 $overlay.show();
 });

 $overlay.click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
});
```

Apparently the problem is somewhere in these lines of code since after I add them, the `preventDefault` stops working and the image opens in a new window like there's no code at all. I want my image to appear inside the overlay when I click on any image (the regular `lightbox` effect) and for the image to disappear when clicking again.

```
 var imageLocation = $(this).attr("href");
 $image.attr("src", imageLocation);
```

The **CSS** for the overlay is

```
  #overlay {

         background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
         display: none;
     }
```

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @eskimo No, I get no errors in the console. Even more frustrating.

Comment: @Tuhin I am using Chrome but I also tried Firefox and it's not working.

Comment: It is working for me on chrome as well as firefox